# Which (real) birds are most strongly associated with fire?

Tags: symbolism, animals

Birds generally are symbols of high power, e.g. the sun. Excluding mythical birds, which real species are most strongly associated with power, magic, and specifically fire in particular?

Answer (score 1):

Several real bird species are called "firebirds":

- subspecies of northern oriole, like [Baltimore oriole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltimore_oriole)
- various birds, having bright scarlet or orange plumage like [Scarlet tanager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_tanager)
- [Sharp-tailed grouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-tailed_grouse)
- [Vermilion flycatcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermilion_flycatcher)